# Opening file in emacs using a shortcut

Tags: key-bindings, find-file

So, I was wondering if I can somehow(with a keyboard shortcut) open a file using the default system dialog, the same way that the big open button does at the top of the window. I didn't find a way to set keyboard shortcut to it directly inside emacs, neither did I find a way to do it in emacs tutorial.

And I do know that there is a way to map the `find-file` command or whatever, but I would still prefer the default systems `find-file` dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to trigger through a key sequence the same command that is triggered when you click in the `File` menu item in the menu bar and then click on `Open file...` in the drop-down menu.

You can ask Emacs what command that is: do `C-h k` then click on the `File` menu and then click on `Open file...`. You will get a `*Help*` buffer that starts like this:

```
There were several key-sequences:

  <select-window> runs the command handle-select-window
  <menu-bar> <file> <open-file> runs the command menu-find-file-existing

They're all described below.
...
```

As you can see, the command is `menu-find-file-existing`. So you can bind that command to a key in the usual way:

```el
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c z") #'menu-find-file-existing)
```

and then invoke the command with `C-c z`.

However, that does not give you the graphical file dialog: it will give you the minibuffer dialog. In order to get the graphical file dialog, you will have to make the function think that it is being called through a mouse click. Here's a modified function that sets up the necessary environment that will make `menu-find-file-existing` think that it was called by clicking on the menu items:

```el
(defun my/fake-menu-find-file-existing ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((use-dialog-box t)
         (use-file-dialog t)
         (last-nonmenu-event nil))
    (menu-find-file-existing)))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c z") #'my/fake-menu-find-file-existing)
```

Now `C-c z` (or whatever you choose to bind the function to) will bring up the graphical file dialog.

Note that we are lying to Emacs, which is never a safe thing to do. I *think* it's not harmful in this case, but there is no warranty: if it breaks, you get to keep the pieces.

---

Details: You might be interested in *how* I came up with the "lying" function above. I used `C-h f` to get the doc string of each function of interest and clicked on the file where the function is defined to examine its source code. I started with `menu-find-file-existing` and found out that it gets the filename by calling `find-file-read-args`. So I did the same things with `find-file-read-args` and found out it calls `read-file-name`, which calls `read-find-file-default`. This one was more complicated, so I had to read the code somewhat carefully to find out how it works. The outcome is that it calls `next-read-file-uses-dialog-p`, a predicate that is callable from Lisp, but is implemented in C, so it's part of the Emacs image that you get when you build it from source (it is in `src/fileio.c` in the Emacs source directory, which you can e.g. clone from Emacs's git repository). That function looks like this:

```c
DEFUN ("next-read-file-uses-dialog-p", Fnext_read_file_uses_dialog_p,
       Snext_read_file_uses_dialog_p, 0, 0, 0,
       doc: /* Return t if a call to `read-file-name' will use a dialog.
The return value is only relevant for a call to `read-file-name' that happens
before any other event (mouse or keypress) is handled.  */)
  (void)
{
#if (defined USE_GTK || defined USE_MOTIF \
     || defined HAVE_NS || defined HAVE_NTGUI || defined HAVE_HAIKU)
  if ((NILP (last_nonmenu_event) || CONSP (last_nonmenu_event))
      && use_dialog_box
      && use_file_dialog
      && window_system_available (SELECTED_FRAME ()))
    return Qt;
#endif
  return Qnil;
}
```

It turns out that the variables it uses can be reached from Lisp as well, so that allowed me to set them up in a way that makes this function return `t` and that fools Emacs and makes it think that `menu-find-file-existing` was called by clicking on the menu.

Obviously, this is *NOT* something that you want to undertake lightly (and maybe not at all!): if the Emacs devs wanted it to be easy they would have provided an easier way (which may exist but I have not found out). I doubly emphasize therefore that there is no warranty: "if it breaks, you get to keep the pieces".

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It now works perfectly.